# Error in the query when the mysql version is 5.7.10 (it works in mysql 5.6.20)

Tags: mysql, database

I needed to migrate to another server host and the MySQL version is different. I asked to change the version, but while this not happen my site return errors.

The main error is in this query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON a.id = p.account_id INNER JOIN
     supplier s
     ON a.id = s.account_id
 WHERE p.status = 1 AND a.type = 'supplier' AND
       s.id IN (SELECT supplier_id FROM supplier_location WHERE location_id IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM location WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id FROM (SELECT @r := 3523) vars, location h WHERE @r <> 0) T1 ) ) AND
       p.name LIKE '%nira%'
ORDER BY p.category_id, p.account_id, p.name ASC
```

In MySQL 5.6.20 it works, but in MySQL 5.7.10 return this error:

```
Unknown column '_id' in 'where clause'
```

Someone knows how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you put some effort into formatting the query?

Comment: Thanks your advice. Is really better with this format. I will remember next time.

Comment: It is not giving any error in MySQL 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by changing

```
(SELECT @r := parent_id FROM location WHERE id = _id)
```

to

```
(SELECT @r := parent_id FROM location WHERE id = @r)
```

The modified query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON a.id = p.account_id INNER JOIN
     supplier s
     ON a.id = s.account_id
 WHERE p.status = 1 AND a.type = 'supplier' AND
       s.id IN (SELECT supplier_id FROM supplier_location WHERE location_id IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM location WHERE id = @r) AS parent_id FROM (SELECT @r := 3523) vars, location h WHERE @r <> 0) T1 ) ) AND
       p.name LIKE '%nira%'
ORDER BY p.category_id, p.account_id, p.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in mysql for that https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549
You should rewrite your query.  Problem is in that_ID is an alias and those arent aprooved in where clausule.